Prove this coordinate function on infinite product space is measurable.
Consider the infinite product measure space
$(\Pi_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n,\mathcal F,\mu ):=\displaystyle\Pi_{n\in\mathbb N}(X_n,\mathcal F_n, \mu_n)$, where $X_n=\{-1,1\},\mathcal F_n=2^{X_n}$, and $\mu_n$ is defined as $\mu_n(\emptyset)=0,\mu_n(\{-1\})=\mu_n(\{1\})=1/2$. (The existence and uniqueness of this product measure space is guaranteed by Theorem 2.4.4 of https://terrytao.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf.)
For each $j$, define $r_j: \Pi_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n\to\mathbb R$ by $r_j(\omega)=\omega_j$ for $\omega=(\omega_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}.$
I want to see that each $r_j$ is measurable.
My attempt is to see that $\{r_j\geqq a\}\in\mathcal F$ for all $a\in\mathbb R.$ Note that $r_j$ only takes the value $-1$ or $1$.
If $a\leqq -1$, $\{r_j\geqq a\}=\Pi_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n\in\mathcal F$.
If $a>1$, $\{r_j\geqq a\}=\emptyset\in\mathcal F$.
But I don't know how to see $\{r_j\geqq a\}\in\mathcal F$ for $-1<a\leqq 1$.
The condition I may use is $\mu_n(\{-1\})=\mu_n(\{1\})=1/2$.
How can I prove $r_j$ is measurable ?

For $-1<a\leqq 1$,  we have ${r_j\geqq a} = (\Pi_{n<j} X_n) \times {1} \times (\Pi_{n>j}X_n) \in \mathcal F$.
